# Get json object array names (metadata) using loadsh

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, json, lodash

I have a json array of objects and want to find a way to get the property names into another array.

```
[
 {
    "ID": 12345,
    "SID": 1111,
    "DataPoint1": [
                    {
                      "Name": "SD",
                      "Activity": "KT",
                      "Group":"Test"
                    }
  }
]
```

I want to be able to extract all the property names of DataPoint1 into its own array:

**New-->**

```
[Name, Activity, Group]
```

I was looking into loadash but couldn't find anything.  Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `_.keys(data[0].DataPoint1[0])` to get the keys as an array.

```js
const data = [{
  "ID": 12345,
  "SID": 1111,
  "DataPoint1": [{
    "Name": "SD",
    "Activity": "KT",
    "Group": "Test"
  }]
}]

console.log(_.keys(data[0].DataPoint1[0]))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks Jonathan!  Marked as answered :)

Answer (score 0):

Answered my own question :)
This did the trick:

```
Object.getOwnPropertyNames(array[0].DataPoint1[0])
```